# about 20% of time opendir script fails. See example

Tags: php, opendir

Hit refresh several times and see sometimes I get "null".

This script loops through a folder to get all mp3 files and randomly selects one.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
if ($handle = opendir('../../hope/upload/php/files/')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        $entry = trim($entry);
        if(preg_match('/.mp3/', $entry))
        {
        $mp3[] =  "$entry";
        }
    }


    closedir($handle);
    $count = count($mp3);

$rand = rand(0,$count -1); /// FIXED BY adding a -1 after count**
$mp3 = $mp3[$rand];

if($mp3)
     {
     echo "http://MyWebsite.com/hope/upload/php/files/$mp3";
     }
else
     {
    echo "null";
     }
}
```

Comment: I could upload a file with a name such as `not.amp3.txt` and your code will consider it one.

Comment: The `preg_match()` statement will also match `notanmp3.exe` as well, since the `.` matches any character.  alex's `glob()` suggestion is probably best, but you might also want to look into [pathinfo()](http://php.net/pathinfo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because array indexes go from `0` to `length - 1`, but your script is generating a random index from `0` to `length`.  The preferred way to fix this would be to use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand):

```
$rand = array_rand($mp3);
$mp3 = $mp3[$rand];
```

Comment: DUDE! WOW... THANK YOU. That was it. This was causing me so much pain in as3, as that is where I was trying to load the sound file. like 10 hours of it... but realized its in the php. thanks my friend, you answeered so fast I could not even click "right answer yet" cause I have to wait 5 min. :)

Comment: I fixed it by adding a -1 after the $count value. :)

Answer (score 1):

You random range is out (the *max* integer is the result of `count()`, and remember the count of an array is one higher than its highest index in an ordinal 0-based array), and your code looks far too verbose.

Try...

```
$mp3s = glob('../../hope/upload/php/files/*.mp3');

$key = array_rand($mp3s);

$randomMp3 = $mp3s[$key];
```

Comment: This is also a great script that works. Wow, I have a lot to learn it seems, about php. Thanks guys.